# how to compare the elements of one array to the index of another array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to compare the elements of an array(Array1) to the positions of the other array(Array2) and generate a new array(Array3) which contains the elements of Array2 whose positions are equal to the elements of Array1.

```
var Array1 = [1, 2, 6] // Dynamic array, maxlength= 6 
var Array2 = [6, 8, 9, 3, 5, 2] // dynamic array of length=6
var Array3 = [6, 8, 2] // note that positions are form 1-6 and not 0-5
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: So what is your expected result? An empty array for your present case?

Comment: Array 3 would be my expected result @Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy

Comment: `array1.map(function(key) {return array2[key];});` - done.

Comment: `array1.map(function(key) {return array2[key - 1];});` - done

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Yup, missed the 1-based part, whoops!

Comment: Awesome!!, It worked.. Thank you @Rajaprabhu and Niet,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to your problem is

```
Array1.map(function(key) {return Array2[key - 1];});
```

The use of `key - 1` has to do with the fact that you are denoting the first element of Array2 as position "1".

If instead you followed the more popular programming convention that the first element of Array2 is position "0" (or *index* 0), then the solution would be

```
Array1.map(function(key) {return Array2[key];});
```